# Does Motorola MC40 support BT LE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola

08-05 14:56:21.304: I/TMDerror(2444): error while reading from socket.
08-05 14:56:21.304: I/TMDerror(2444): java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
08-05 14:56:21.304: I/IS_SOCKET_CONNECTED(2444): true

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask for product specs. I'm sure you can find a spec sheet for that device somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

The original [Motorola Solution (now Zebra Technologies) MC40](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/mc40.html#mainpartabscontainer=detailed-specs) does not support Bluetooth Low Energy (or [Bluetooth SMART as is now the official name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy)).

There's no HW support on the original device and Bluetooth SMART support has been introduced in Android only with v4.3. The MC40 was introduced in Q1 2013 with Android v2.3.4.

There will be a new version of the MC40 coming with an updated OS and Bluetooth HW this summer. This version of the MC40 will support Bluetooth SMART.

If you need a device similar to the MC40 with Bluetooth SMART support that is already released, you can look into the [Zebra Technologies TC70](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/tc70.html).